# <Priority queue>Why values are compared twice?

Tags: stl, queue, priority-queue, predicate

```
struct St {
    int e;
    bool operator < (const St &s) const {
        cout << "e" << e << endl;
        cout << "s" << s.e << endl;
        return e > s.e;
    }
};
int main() {
        priority_queue<St> q;
        St s1, s2, s3, s4;
        s1.e = 5;
        s2.e = 3;
        s3.e = 7;
        s4.e = 2;
        q.push(s1);
        cout << "ssssss1" << endl;
        q.push(s2);
        cout << "ssssss2" << endl;
        q.push(s3);
        cout << "ssssss3" << endl;
        q.push(s4);
        cout << "ssssss4" << endl;
        cout << q.top().e;
        return 0;
    }
```

The result will be like this.

```
ssssss1
e5
s3
e3
s5
ssssss2
e3
s7
ssssss3
e5
s2
e2
s5
e3
s2
e2
s3
ssssss4
2
```

Why the values are compared twice when pushed s2 and s4?

Comment: Running a debug build, by any chance? Many library implementations perform extraneous comparisons in debug build, to verify that your comparison predicate is actually valid. Predicates that don't satisfy requirements are a common source of bugs.

Comment: It looks like Igor's comment is correct. The data you've shown indicates that the code is doing an extra comparison whenever a swap is made. So in the first case it had to swap 5 and 3. Once swapped, the comparison is re-done with the parameters reversed. The only reason I can think of for that spurious comparison is to verify that your comparison function is returning the correct values. Run a non-debug build of this and see if the spurious comparisons go away.